# Font Size - Translating to actual point size

Tags: html, css, font-size

Quick question for everyone:

Does anybody know what the actual point size would be when setting the font-size to the following values:

- Large
- Larger
- Medium
- Small
- Smaller
- X-Large
- X-Small
- XX-Large
- XX-Small

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Font sizes to pixels are explained by this chart:

[image]

Comment: What is your source - Can you please add a link?

Comment: @anuswadh Sorry, it's been 2+ years....no clue where I got it.  But, it's still accurate!

Answer (score 24):

It may vary by browser slightly but for the most part this should work:

Large is 18 px which is around 13.5 pt

Larger is 19 px which is around 14 pt

Medium is 16 px which is around 12 pt

Small is 13 px which is around 10 pt

Smaller is 13 px which is around 10 pt

X-large is 24 px which is around 18 pt

X-small is 10 px which is around 7.5 pt

XX-large is 32 px which is around 24 pt

XX-small is 9 px which is around 7 pt

This is based off of seeing the computed font-size style in pixels and converting from [this chart](http://sureshjain.wordpress.com/2007/07/06/53/). [This link](http://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/) might also be helpful.

Comment: font-size: larger is 120% of initial, which is 16px as 100%, so larger = 19.2px

Answer (score 4):

`medium` is the user's preferred font size. All other values are defined by the browser. ([source](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-size-props))

Answer (score 1):

Two good weblinks might answer this:

- [Font Conversion Tables](http://jerekdain.com/fontconversion.html)
- [CSS Font-Size: em vs. px vs. pt vs. percent](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/)

Comment: I can't find the second link.

Comment: @ChrisW The link is gone. I've put another link in there! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use java script then you can, using a canvas element, measure the height of a given font size. The size will return a value in pixels for the height of the font you specify. This will only work if the user has calibrated their screen: most have not but the default values are generally close for most monitor setups.

```
var cvs = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
ctx.font="30px Arial";
var txt="Hello World";
var size = ctx.measureText(txt).height;
```

Comment: `TextMeasure` doesn't have a `height` property, though, it seems.